# Feature selection using Lasso with scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I want to do some kind of feature selection using python and scikit-learn library.

As I know, Lasso regression can be used for feature selection like univariate selection.

My simple dataset is like this.

```
G1  G2  G3  ... GN Class
1.0 4.0 5.0 ... 1.0 X
4.0 5.0 9.0 ... 1.0 X
9.0 6.0 3.0 ... 2.0 Y
...
```

I want to find top-N Attributes(Gs) which could affect much to class, with lasso regression. Although I have to handle parameters, lasso regression can be applied like this.

```
lasso = Lasso()
# A = list of [G1, G2, ..., GN], B = [X, X, Y, ...]
lasso.fit(A, B) 
print (lasso.coef_)
```

Is it right to decide that the attribute is more related to Class if it has a higher value of lasso.coef_?
Also, I want to know whether there is some rule for choosing top-N genes using regression. If I use PCC, P-value such as .05 can be used as a threshold for selection, but I do not know how to deal with Lasso.
Can someone give me an idea please?

Comment: So just to clarify, you're asking about what the lasso coefficients mean in terms of feature importance?

Comment: @NBartley You are right. I am also asking if there are some kind of rules for deciding whether a feature with a certain value coefficients(or other value) is important or not. Thank you.